# Django: How to display foreign key objects of a model in manual form field as choices

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, foreign-keys

So I have 2 models called Billing and Organization as shown below. Billing in the admin site works as expected i.e the organization field shows all organizations listed and gives me an option to pick one. If I implement a model form for Billing it doesn't display all organizations that I can pick from. How to Implement this? I have shared forms.py, views.py code below.

**models.py**

```py
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)



class Billing(models.Model):
    invoice_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.invoice_name)
```

**views.py**

```py
class BillingCreateView(AdminStaffRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Billing
    form_class = forms.BillingCreateForm
    template_name = 'dashboard/billing_new.html'
    success_message = 'Invoice has been created successfully!'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**dashboard/billing_new.html**

```
<!-- start form -->
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <form method="post" action="{% url 'product_create' %}" class="mailform off2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="row">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                                    {{ form.invoice_name }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                                    {{ form.organization }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                                    {{ form.product }}
                                </div>
                                {% if redirect_field_value %}
                                <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
                                {% endif %}
                                <div class="mfControls col-md-12 offset-md-3 text-left mt-2">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn white">{% trans "CREATE" %}</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                </div>
                <!-- end form -->
```

**forms.py**

```py
class BillingCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = models.Billing
        fields = ['invoice_name', 'organization', 'product']
        widgets = {
            'invoice_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'text', 'name': 'name', 'placeholder': 'Invoice Name:'}),
            'organization': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'text', 'name': 'name', 'placeholder': 'Company:'}),
            'items': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'text', 'name': 'name', 'placeholder': 'Items:'}),
        }
```

Comment: You can Implement with ajax with rest api

Comment: @AsaduzzamanSohel It was a simple issue. I have posted the fix below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by using `forms.select` widget in forms.py as follows:-

```
class BillingCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = models.Billing
    fields = ['invoice_name', 'organization', 'product']
    widgets = {
        'invoice_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'text', 'name': 'name', 'placeholder': 'Invoice Name:'}),
        'organization': forms.Select(attrs={'type': 'text', 'name': 'name', 'placeholder': 'Company:'}),
        'items': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'text', 'name': 'name', 'placeholder': 'Items:'}),
    }
```